# Tufte-Latex: How do I stop marginfigure from inserting inline space?

Tags: spacing, marginpar, tufte, marginnote

I want to use marginfigure, but it is inserting space inline. Check out my minimal example:

```
documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
Hello\begin{marginfigure}$2+2=4$\end{marginfigure}I'm new here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the "Hello I'm new here" is two different lines--I want a single line. Of course, one "solution" is to simply move the marginfigure; however, this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The culprit appears to be the `\FloatBarrier` command (provided by the [`placeins` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins)).  If we remove the `\FloatBarrier` command from the code that generates the `marginfigure`, then no space is inserted:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% Remove \FloatBarrier from marginfigure definition
% to prevent unwanted spaces.
\makeatletter% so we can use @ commands
\renewenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]{%
  %\FloatBarrier% removed because it adds unwanted white space
  \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
    \@tufte@caption@font
    \def\@captype{#2}%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \@tufte@caption@justification
    \@tufte@margin@par
    \noindent
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}}%
}
\makeatother% restore meaning of @


\begin{document}

Hello\begin{marginfigure}$2+2=4$\end{marginfigure}I'm new here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make this work in Lyx, simply remove `\makeatletter% so we can use @ commands`  and `\makeatother% restore meaning of @` from the code and use everything else in between inside Document>Settings>LaTeX Preamble for Lyx.

Comment: But is this simply a bug in `tufte-latex`, or is there some drawback to removing `\FloatBarrier`?

Comment: Removing `\FloatBarrier` could allow LaTeX to place earlier figures after the margin figure so the numbering would appear out of sequence. You could remove `\FloatBarrier` and, if you notice there's a problem, write `\FloatBarrier` yourself in between paragraphs where it won't cause spacing problems.

Comment: Thank you godbyk... this is *SO* useful! (+1)